# Starting a directory with a + in a URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

For long and complicated reasons which I won't go into, is there any reason why you can't start a 'directory' with a + ?

For example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/+helloworld
```

Note that it's not actually a directory, it's being mapped using a rewriterule

Just checking...

?

+Note : Similar to the old school tilda ~ but I don't want to use ~ because nobody knows where it is on the keyboard

Comment: It's a bad idea in general -- you really would like to stick to the safe characters only(especially for the first character in URL segment): `a-zA-Z0-9_-`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this?

```
rewriterule ^\+helloworld$ /test.html
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've not got a problem doing it. The question was just whether it was acceptable URL format to do it at all ?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use it to refer, in general symbol `+` in URL refers to `whitespace`:
http://trprod.proofstat.com/homepages/webcatalog/cec/specs/special_c.htm